# Multiple TTL sensors on serial RX GPIO 10

Tags: gpio, usb, serial, sensor

Is it possible to read more than one TTL sensor on serial RX GPIO 10?
I know you can add multiple serial sensors on /dev/ttyUSBx

Does the same apply to /dev/ttyAMAx ?

Comment: The answer is probably no.  To be sure we would need to know the serial sensors you plan to use.

Comment: Maxbotix 7389 Ultrasonic TTL version running 3.3vdc.   https://www.maxbotix.com/documents/HRXL-MaxSonar-WR_Datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

While I have not been able to find a way to read multiple TTL sensors on a single GPIO pin, I did find this way of using other GPIO pins as serial RX pins via the pigpio library.
Works great.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_serial_read

And a link to simple python code for reading a given GPIO pin as serial:

https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/raspberry-pi-2nd-uart-a-k-a-bit-banging-a-k-a-software-serial

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

Use a MUX IC between the sensors and the pin. That should work.